# How to filter out records from one database from another

Tags: mysql, database, filter

I have 2 table, table A have `22000` records and table B have `12000` records in the range of 1 dec to 10 dec.

I would like would like to filter out the 8000 records that are not in table A.

Both table shares the same date structure.

```
uid,tid and insert_date
```

i wonder whats the fastest way to filter them in sql?

Cheers

Comment: did you try using JOIN feature? you can put the uncommon rows in ON of JOIN so they show the uncommon ones only

Answer (score 0):

assuming uid is the key to identify records:

```
SELECT * FROM B LEFT JOIN A 
ON A.uid=B.uid WHERE A.TID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Also assume uid is the key to identify records:

```
SELECT * FROM B LEFT JOIN A 
ON A.uid=B.uid
```

*Note that, in some databases LEFT JOIN is called LEFT OUTER JOIN.*